# Binding RowDetails in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I cant seem to find how to do this.

I dont see why the datacontext for a rowdetailstemplate becomes the datacontext of the datagrid parent. When it cleary should choose the rowitem from the datagrid itemssource.

```
<DataGrid  Grid.Row="1" x:Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" 
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>          
        <TextBox Text="{Binding WhyDoesThisBindingUseDataContextOfDatGridParentAndNotTheRowDataObject}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate></DataGrid>
```

How can i get the rowdataobject as the datacontext for my template?

Comment: well it usually is rowItem, there is problem smwhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the visual tree.

[image]

Object which you binds to ItemsSource doesn't apply to RowDetailsTemplate. It takes DataContext of DataGrid Parent.

Comment: Well the solution is to ignore what intellisense says and simply treat these controls the same as if the rowdetails looks at the rowbound item for its data. It works now but i get warnings everywhere in my RowDetailstemplate that the bound properties are not found even though they are.