# Button is not firing inside the DataGridRow details

Tags: c#, wpf

I have one datagrid, clicking on datagridrow, need to show dynamic button details below the row.But button click is not working for me.

I have added code snippet below.

In User Control resources

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="rowDT" >
            <StackPanel Loaded="StackPanel_Loaded" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                        Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Datagrid xaml details

```
<DataGrid Name="dgUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding Interactions,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  CanUserAddRows="false" IsReadOnly="True" Background="White" RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}" >
                            <DataGrid.Columns >
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="QUEUE" Binding="{Binding Queue}" Width="100"  />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

I code behind Constructor

```
var rowDetailsTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["rowDT"];
dgUsers.RowDetailsTemplate= rowDetailsTemplate;
```

and in stack panel loaded event I am loading my button

```
private void StackPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StackPanel templateChildPanel = sender as StackPanel;
 Button InteractionViewButton = new Button
            {
                Width = 150,
                Height = 30,
                Content = "VIEW CALL DETAILS",
                Style = this.FindResource("RegularButton") as Style,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center            

        };
  InteractionViewButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(InteractionViewButton_Click);
templateChildPanel.Children.Add(InteractionViewButton );               
                }
```

but button click is not firing? How to solve this?

Comment: "How to solve this?" -  define template in xaml completely and assign it to RowDetailsTemplate in xaml as well.

Comment: I have tried as per u mentioned. But is not worked.

Comment: Where is the method that your button should execute? RowDetails has a particular behaviour regarding DataContext. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602371/binding-rowdetails-in-wpf-datagrid). Also, in my opinion, adding stuff using code behind over complicate very much your work. You should define the controls using the xaml for much better readability and management of your code